# Operator overload: Multuplying matrices

Tags: c++, matrix, operator-overloading

I'm trying to set some overloading operator functions for matrices where I used the constructor to dynamically allocate them, and an istream operator for setting values. I have encountered a problem when trying to multiply two matrices (run time error).

Any help would be appreciated.
ps: I'm not familiar with templates.

Here is my * operator function:

```
matrixType operator*(matrixType m)
{
    if( Rows==m.Cols && Cols==m.Rows)
    {
        matrixType m3(Rows,m.Cols);
        for( int i=0; i<Rows;i++)
        {
            for( int j=0; j<Cols; j++)
            {
                {
                  for(int g=0; g<Cols;g++)
                      m3.matrix[i][j]+=matrix[i][g] * m.matrix[g][j];
                }
            }
        }
        return m3;
    }
}
```

And here is my copy operator function:

```
matrixType& operator=( matrixType& m)
{
    for (int i =0; i<Rows; i++)
    {
         for ( int j=0; j<Cols; j++)
                matrix[i][j]=m.matrix[i][j];
    }

    return *this;
}
```

Comment: You're not mentioning any details about the error, but the most common problem is to not follow "the rule of three" (google it) when you have dynamically allocated members. It's better to use `std::vector` though, as that lets you follow "the rule of zero".

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

I think it would be better if you post some runtime error when you run the code. Anyway, I found a problem in your Multiply operator function:

when you return m3, it is defined in another scope, therefore it is not defined, how about you put return m3 statement inside the if scope:

```
matrixType operator*(matrixType m)
{
    if( Rows==m.Cols && Cols==m.Rows)
    {
        matrixType m3(Rows,m.Cols);
        for( int i=0; i<Rows;i++)
        {
            for( int j=0; j<Cols; j++){
                    {for(int g=0; g<Cols;g++)
                    m3.matrix[i][j]+=matrix[i][g] * m.matrix[g][j];}
        }
        return m3;
    }
      // Throw some error if your assertion is not satisfied, perhaps
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're using the wrong `Cols` in your `j` loop.  You want `m.Cols` there:

```
for (for( int j=0; j<m.Cols; j++)
```

Look at where the `i`, `j`, and `g` variables are used for subscripting to see what the limit values are for the 3 loops.